# How do I access variables in C from different functions?

Tags: c, function, pointers, scope

my question is how does the function malloc_queue() can access variables from init_queue() **without** giving any arguments!

For example:

The main.c:

```
if (init_queue()) {
    malloc_queue()
}
```

init_queue() creates the variable que:

```
int init_queue{
    struct Queue *que;
    return 1;
}
```

malloc_queue() want to do something with the variable que from init_queue():

```
void malloc_queue{
    struct Queue *que = (struct Queue*)malloc(sizeof(struct Queue));
    return;
}
```

but that doesnt work since malloc_queue doesnt know what que is. Are there any possible ways without giving any arguments?

Comment: Read everything you can about the **scope** of identifiers. Especially look for *file scope*.

Comment: you have to have variables declared in where they are used.

Comment: @user3717963 You need to rewrite the functions because they are simply wrong.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow why are they wrong?

Comment: @user3717963 First of all syntaxically they are defined incorectly and they do not make a sense. For example what is the task of init_queue?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow init_queue is creating a queue.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow http://codeshare.io/bRHZV. At line 12-14 i have to save those new 3 elements somehow. but how do i do it?

Comment: @user3717963 Your init_queue creates nothing.

Comment: @user3717963 , Those will not compile. You need `()`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because asking how to solve a problem in a ridiculous way isn't likely to help future readers.

Comment: Take a break, grap your favorite C primer and flip to chapter "Basics  - How to define a function." Read, think over your sources and if still things are unclear you are welcome to come back here. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want a `static variable` outside functions, which has scope inside the residing file after its definition.

Check this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int x = 0;
void a() {
    x = 5;
}
void b() {
    x*=2;
}
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    printf("%d\n", x);

    a();
    printf("%d\n", x);

    b();
    printf("%d\n", x);

    return 0;
}
```

Just as the comments suggested, read about c scopes.

---

If you need to declare struct other than primary types, you might need to declare a pointer to structure as the `static variable` outside function, then allocate memory (e.g `malloc()`) inside one of your functions.

Comment: just got the answer. I declare right now the variables in a header. Is it a good idea?

Comment: @user3717963 Typically, headers are for constants and function prototype. First, you should know the scope of your variable, if it only use in a single file, then declared in the way my answer described. Again, if you plan to use c in long term, please read a book named `Thc c progrramming language 2nd` first. You will get more than what you asked.